# outE() not showing edge, but inE() shows the edge in Cosmos DB for Gremlin

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have two vertices in two different logical partitions, (both have different partition key values). I have created an Edge between them. Now when I run the outE() on the source vertex, it returns null, while when I run the inE() on destination Vertex, it returns me the edge with outV as the source vertex.

These are the gremlin queries for the same,

```
g.addV(‘vertex_label_1’).property(‘id’,’V1’).property(‘pk’,’pkX’)
g.addV(‘vertex_label_2’).property(‘id’,’V2’).property(‘pk’,’pkY’)
```

Add Edge:

```
g.V(‘V1’).has(‘pk’,’pkX’).addE(‘edge_label_12’).property(‘id’,’E12’).to(g.V(‘V2’).has(‘pk’,’pkY’))
```

Now when I run g.V('V1').outE() -> it returns null
while when I run g.V('V2').inE() -> it returns the above edge

I am not sure what am I missing here ?

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1286272/how-to-add-an-edge-between-2-vertices-in-different

Comment: The outgoing edges are stored in the partition with their source vertices. Because you are doing a query that goes cross partition you likely see that behavior, but even if it would be possible it will result in a very expensive query (scaling with your data). A better solution would be to setup bidirectional edges so you can query either side with `OutE` if that's a requirement for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I run the outE() on the source vertex, it returns null, while when I run the inE() on destination Vertex, it returns me the edge with outV as the source vertex.

As @NotFound suggested to setup `bidirectional` edges. So, that we can query either side with  **OutE()**. I used that approach to get same **Edge** while querying with either of the query.

Below are the steps I followed which returns same **Edge 'E12'**:

Add Vertex **V1**:

- `g.addV('vertex_label_1').property('id', 'V1').property('pk', 'pkX')` Creates a vertex with label **vertex_label_1**, id **V1**, and `partition key` **pkX**.

```js
[
  {
    "id": "V1",
    "label": "vertex_label_1",
    "type": "vertex",
    "properties": {
      "pk": [
        {
          "id": "V1|pk",
          "value": "pkX"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Add Vertex **V2**:

- `g.addV('vertex_label_2').property('id', 'V2').property('pk', 'pkY')` Creates a vertex with label **vertex_label_2**, id **V2**, and `partition key` **pkY**.

```js
[
  {
    "id": "V2",
    "label": "vertex_label_2",
    "type": "vertex",
    "properties": {
      "pk": [
        {
          "id": "V2|pk",
          "value": "pkY"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Creating a bidirectional relationship between **V1** and **V2**:

- `g.V('V1').has('pk', 'pkX').as('v1')` The property **pk** with the value **pkX** on vertex **V1** is selected, and an alias of **v1** is given to it.
- `.V('V2').has('pk', 'pkY').as('v2')` The property **pk** with the value **pkY** on vertex **V2** is selected, and an alias of **v2** is given to it.
- `.addE('edge_label_12').property('id', 'E12').from('v1').to('v2')` It generates a new edge with the label **edge_label_12** and ID **E12**. It links to the vertex known as **v2** after starting from the vertex known as **v1**.
- This establishes the first direction of the edge, going from **V1** to **V2**.
- `.addE('edge_label_12').property('id', 'E12').from('v2').to('v1')` The same ID **E12** is used to construct a second new edge with the label **edge_label_12**. It links to the vertex **v1** after starting from the **v2**.
- This establishes the edge's second direction, from **V2** to **V1**.

**Query:**

```
g.V('V1').has('pk', 'pkX').as('v1')
  .V('V2').has('pk', 'pkY').as('v2')
  .addE('edge_label_12').property('id', 'E12').from('v1').to('v2')
  .addE('edge_label_12').property('id', 'E12').from('v2').to('v1')
```

```js
[
  {
    "id": "E12",
    "label": "edge_label_12",
    "type": "edge",
    "inVLabel": "vertex_label_1",
    "outVLabel": "vertex_label_2",
    "inV": "V1",
    "outV": "V2"
  }
]
```

- `g.V('V1').outE()` The **V1** vertex outgoing edges are returned by the query. The edge **E12** that joins **V1** and **V2** is accurately returned by the output shown below:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "E12",
    "label": "edge_label_12",
    "type": "edge",
    "inVLabel": "vertex_label_2",
    "outVLabel": "vertex_label_1",
    "inV": "V2",
    "outV": "V1"
  }
]
```

- `g.V('V2').inE()` Returns the incoming edges to vertex **V2**. The report accurately identifies the edge **E12**, which joins **V1** and **V2**.

```js
[
  {
    "id": "E12",
    "label": "edge_label_12",
    "type": "edge",
    "inVLabel": "vertex_label_2",
    "outVLabel": "vertex_label_1",
    "inV": "V2",
    "outV": "V1"
  }
]
```

- `g.V('V2').outE()` retrieves all outgoing edges from vertex **V2**.

```js
[
  {
    "id": "E12",
    "label": "edge_label_12",
    "type": "edge",
    "inVLabel": "vertex_label_1",
    "outVLabel": "vertex_label_2",
    "inV": "V1",
    "outV": "V2"
  }
]
```

- `g.V('V1').outE()` , `g.V('V2').inE()` and `g.V('V2').outE()`  Returning the same edge **E12**, suggesting that **V1** and **V2** are stored in the same partition, regardless of their different partition key values.